# What does "power1: 4.29 MW (interval = 1.00 s)" mean? That is, what is the "MW" unit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sensors

I installed the `lm-sensors` on my Ubuntu platform in order to check the temperature of my processors and possibly some other info.

When I run the command, I see the following:

```
alexis~$ sensors
power_meter-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
power1:        4.29 MW (interval =   1.00 s)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 1:        +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 3:        +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 4:        +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 5:        +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 6:        +40.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 7:        +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 8:        +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 9:        +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 10:       +40.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 11:       +40.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 12:       +41.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 13:       +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 14:       +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 15:       +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 1:  +41.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 1:        +37.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 2:        +37.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 3:        +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 4:        +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 5:        +37.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 6:        +40.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 7:        +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 8:        +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 9:        +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 10:       +39.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 11:       +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 12:       +37.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 13:       +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 14:       +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
Core 15:       +38.0°C  (high = +81.0°C, crit = +91.0°C)
```

I'm wondering about the first line:

```
power1:        4.29 MW (interval =   1.00 s)
```

What does `4.29 MW` stand for in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The scaling function](https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/blob/d20ecfd4e8b7175dc2440277b76be42ab07bb542/prog/sensors/chips.c#L541) used here uses SI prefixes, where “M” corresponds to 10<sup>6</sup>, so “4.29 MW” means “4.29 megawatts” (and your system is presumably reporting incorrect values, or `sensors` is mis-interpreting them).

Comment: Okay, so I read it correctly the first time. It's just that my server is not in need of a full Nuclear plant to run. :-)